# How to map the structure of one generic type to another with custom transformation functions, such that it remains type-safe at compile-time?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a function that can map one generic object to another, using custom transformations. Something like:

```
interface Input {
    str: string;
    num: number;
}

interface Output {
    str: number;
    num: string;
}
```

where...

```
const input: Input = {
    str: "78",
    num: 1
}

const output: Output = transform(transformations)(input); 
// where 'transformations' is a bunch of callbacks to provide custom transformation
```

E.g. 2 such callbacks might look like

```
type Transform<T, R> = (val: T) => R;
const transformString: Transform<string, number> = (val) => parseFloat(val);
const transformNumber: Transform<number, string> = (val) => `${val}`;
```

Here is a playground link of what I currently have: https://tsplay.dev/wEVQ3N

Comment: ehh without higher kinded types (of the sort requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)) I don't think you can reasonably express arbitrary compositions of transformations in the type system.  If you have some fixed set of transformations then you might be able to do it, but that's equivalent to just writing the composed thing in the first place.

Comment: I wasn't aware of "higher-kinded types." My answer below was the best I could do given the current tools. It works for me in my case as I can provide some sensible transformation defaults which the user can use to remove their burden. And I'll be reusing my particular mapper in lots of locations. So definitely a big help! But it's not the correct answer and I won't mark it as such

Comment: If I start trying to do this the closest I can get is something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9AeqN), but the compiler cannot carry the generics of composed transformations down into mapped types.  This is before I even get to the recursive part of it.  I might write this up as an answer but for now it's "this is probably too hard to write in current TS".  There are ways to simulate higher kinded types but they are probably more trouble than they're worth here.

Comment: Wow, you got very close! For my purposes, union types are not actually an issue as we don't have any in this area of the codebase. So if your approach can achieve nesting, then I could mark it as a correct answer (until TS adds support for higher-kinded types).

Comment: You need arbitrary nesting?  Or is it sufficient to describe `Output` in terms of `Input` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w62Kyw)?  Note how I call `mapTransforms()` multiple times.  If that works I'll write it up.

Comment: Yep that solution is great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While TypeScript doesn't directly support *higher kinded types* of the sort needed to express completely arbitrary type transformations (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)), you might be able to compose a few basic transformations that meet your needs.

Let's start with your `Transform<I, O>` function type that takes an input of type `I` and produces an output of type `O`:

```
type Transform<I, O> = (val: I) => O;
```

If you have an object type `T` whose properties are each `Transformation`s, you can use that to create a `Transform<I, O>` where `I` is an object type with the same keys as `T` and whose property values come from all the transformation *input* types, and where `O` is an object type with the same keys as `T` and whose property values come from all the transformation *output* types.  Let's call this `MapObject<T>`:

```
type MapObject<T extends Record<keyof T, Transform<any, any>>> = Transform<
    { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Transform<infer I, any> ? I : never },
    { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Transform<any, infer O> ? O : never }
>;
```

For example, `MapObject<{a: Transform<V, W>, b: Transform<X, Y>}>` will be a `Transform<{a: V, b: X}, {a: W, b: Y}`.  And you can make a function `mapTransforms()` that takes a `transformMap` of type `T` and produces an output of type `MapObject<T>`, by iterating through the object entries of `transformMap`:

```
function mapTransforms<T extends Record<keyof T, Transform<any, any>>>(
  transformMap: T
): MapObject<T> {
    return (x: any): any =>
        Object.fromEntries((Object.entries(x) as Array<[keyof T, any]>)
          .map(([k, v]) => [k, transformMap[k](v)]));
}
```

Here I've used [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) a few times to stop the compiler from complaining about the implementation of `mapTransforms()`.  While you can express "`T` → `MapObject<T>`" in the type system, it's hard/impossible to get the compiler to actually verify that a particular function implementation is of that type.  Using `any` circumvents that... meaning I have to take care that the implementation is correct; the compiler won't be able to catch mistakes here.

---

To test this, let's define three functions of type `Transform<string, number>`, `Transform<number, string>`, and `Transform<boolean, A<boolean>>`:

```
const str2Num = (x: string) => +x;
const num2Str = (x: number) => "" + x;
const bool2A = (x: boolean): A<boolean> => ({ name: x });
```

and call `mapTransforms()` to turn them into a `Transform<Input, Output>`:

```
const inputToOutput: Transform<Input, Output> = mapTransforms({
    x: str2Num,
    y: num2Str,
    z: bool2A,
    nest: mapTransforms({
        a: num2Str
    })
});
```

That compiles with no error, so the compiler at least thinks that the output of `mapTransforms()` is of the desired type.  And we can test it with your example at runtime:

```
const input: Input = {
    x: "22",
    y: 33,
    z: false,
    nest: {
        a: 66
    }
}
const output = inputToOutput(input);

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
// {"x":22,"y":"33","z":{"name":false},"nest":{"a":"66"}}
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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-WbJBgMIxLTyw6wqzWIMgsbmm4wW0gKMraCFC8XWKoWgaBGnipns2wkGBdmbYfjw863fx8SA6nao3BV4EAF6N6ud5A7gL1C2sBf4wIIDeR4onlplsc0idZ6AkOez+d48NITf3vF13NWkkFdB99ygdtDy7LYC3pYALzxfEb2Al1QIfDYjQrbovxgDAP2AL9UgBSZ8BnOdiAIr8eygaVznyBlLwCJcrVtbA2jXW9g3+Di9wPGs614094NYOiSMuGgmKvFC-2wbi4DxZp2DLZTjWOf0YiI6cvw8KTw1jS1LVjISoCAgBmMyTIgzNGBQCATLPBD8yva9WAANjcxSn2wjBPznDxNLnPCqLnGhAuAUc1NQZtiUYDBXRoAApIMSGtYll1AqI0BAGhfMIud2FHAB6IrgljVRY2YQzCFjEBKtjCzjNjXdKqCWMBwgSqbLs1p2vg1rYwQeqPNjZojQEIA)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I used to solve this, however it requires a set of defined transformations (e.g. in a `Transformations` object) to achieve it. This doesn't allow me to add new transformations easily, as any changes must be reflected in the `Transformations` object as well a couple of other types as well, and then handled specifically in `createGenericObjectMapper`.

I'll leave this solution here for anyone who might find it valuable.

https://tsplay.dev/Nd3nMw

Comment: Hmm, you're the one with the question, but I don't see how this addresses "map one generic object to another, using custom transformations".  The code here only processes a single specific `Transformations` input type, and if you had different transformations you'd have to... modify that type?  And the `createGenericObjectMapper()` function as well?

Comment: BTW, if you want this answer to stay, you should probably explain what's going on and include the code as plain text.

Comment: Yes :( You're right, this doesn't solve the question directly and therefore I'm only leaving this answer here for those who are happy to do it in a "manual" way. I will make note of this in the answer.